# CSS Media Query functionality

Tags: css, jekyll

I have a probably very easy to solve question for someone who really knows how to...

From available code I mixed some css that for the moment does what I'm looking for, but only in a closed environment. When I include it into an exisiting jekyll template it just produces rubbish.

Here's the funtionality (containers -- at the moment px and em are mixed, never mind)

```
.columnsContainer {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}

.leftColumn {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em ) {
  .leftColumn { margin-right: 21em; }
    .rightColumn { position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 20em;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

.head-img {
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 95%;
    background-color: $white;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I want to include it into a jekyll theme with the exisiting media query which at the moment is:

```
$on-palm:          500px;
$on-laptop:        650px;


@mixin media-query($device) {
    @media screen and (max-width: $device) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

How do I manage to make theses two work together?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Add another media query to main.css:

```
@mixin media-query-two($device) {
    @media screen and (min-width: $device) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Now, there are other issues...